# Function call optimization in V8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Does V8 optimize multiple function calls that are the same function and arguments? In the example below Variance is called twice with the same arguments.

```
var Variance = require('variance');

function summary(items) {        
    return {
      variance: Variance(items.value.map((item) => item.value)),
      standardDeviation: Math.sqrt(Variance(items.value.map((item) => item.value))),
    };
}
```

Comment: It will probably try, but to make your code shorter (and easier to maintain), why not just call it once by yourself?

Comment: why don't you put it in a variable? (I don't know if there's an optimizaton)

Comment: This example is contrived.  I'm just curious if v8 does this optimization and was having difficulty finding an answer on google.

Comment: Calling two times the same function with the same arguments doesn't necessarily means you will get the same result. I'm unsure if v8 is capable of detecting that a complex function has no side effect. In your case, I guess `Variance` is simple as it doesn't contain other function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v8 does optimize functions called repeatedly with the same arguments, but in your example those are not actually the same arguments (they are different object/array references).